# SmartContract/Solidity: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I have the code below inside a contract, whenever I run the function **getTimeUntilRewrdClaimable** it works until the time is under zero.. If the time is under zero it throws this error...

```
VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you 
send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

My Code inside my contract:

```
mapping( uint256 => ObjectDetails) private attributes;

// Object Structure...
struct ObjectDetails {
    uint dailyClaim;
    uint lastClaimDate;
}


function getTimeUntilRewrdClaimable(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (int) {
    return int(attributes[tokenId].lastClaimDate + 60 - block.timestamp);
}
```

Thanks to any and all feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attributes[tokenId].lastClaimDate` is a uint, so `attributes[tokenId].lastClaimDate + 60 - block.timestamp` is as well. This causes an issue when `attributes[tokenId].lastClaimDate + 60` is less than `block.timestamp`. To fix, cast both parts to int before doing the subtraction:

```
return int(attributes[tokenId].lastClaimDate + 60) - int(block.timestamp);
```